# firebase authentication custom attribute failure

Tags: javascript, firebase-authentication

I have been putting together a website and i've been using the latest firebase script and everything.
When I request for a custom user attribute that has been created it says it's 'undefined'.

CustomAttributes:
points
ownedavatars
Code:

SignUp

```
var user = firebase.auth().currentUser;
user.updateProfile({
  displayName: //username,
  photoURL: //icon,
  points: 0,
  ownedavatars: "default"
}).then(function() {
  user.sendEmailVerification().then(function() {
    //it would save email and password and then redirect here
  }).catch(function(error) {
    console.log(error.message);
  });
}).catch(function(error) {
  console.log(error.message);
});
```

Login

```
var listofavatars;
firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).then(function() {
  var user = firebase.auth().currentUser;
  if (user != null) {
    document.getElementById("user").innerHTML = user.displayName;
    if (user.points == undefined) {
      document.getElementById("points").innerHTML = "0p";
    } else {
      document.getElementById("points").innerHTML = user.points + "p";
    }
    listofavatars = user.ownedavatars;
    if (user.photoURL == "default") {
      document.getElementById("avatar").src = //would pull default;
    } else {
      document.getElementById("avatar").src = //would pull any other icon saved; 
    }
  }
}).catch(function(error) {
  alert(error.message + " Code:" + error.code);
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use `updateProfile` to save arbitrary custom user variables. This API only currently supports `photoURL` and displayName`. To save other user data, you have to use a separate database to do so. You can use Firebase realtime database or Firestore to do so. Here is an example how to save user specific data securely: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/user-security

If you need to save user specific data for role based access control, you can use the Firebase Admin SDK to set custom user attributes:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/custom-claims

However, it is highly recommended that this custom user data is to be used for access control. For other data, use a dedicated database as described above.